# How to replace anything that is not a letter with a space with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I need to remove everything that is not a letter, lowercase or uppercase, from a file and replace it with a space, e.g.:

```
The bear ate 3 snakes, then ate 50% of the fish from the river.
```

This becomes:

```
The bear ate   snakes  then ate     of the fish from the river
```

- Sometimes the file contains unusual characters. It is saved as UTF-8.

How can I replace any non-letters with a space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo "The bear ate 3 snakes, then ate 50% of the fish from the river." | sed "s/[^a-zA-Z]/ /g"
The bear ate   snakes  then ate     of the fish from the river
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want support for unicode letters `(as mentioned in your question)` then this perl command to replace all `unicode non-letters`:

```
echo $line | perl -pe 's/[^\p{L}\s]+/ /g;'
```

Reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
echo 'The bear ate 3 snakes, then ate 50% of the fish from the river.' | 
tr -c '[:alpha:]' ' '
The bear ate   snakes  then ate     of the fish from the river
```

or:

```
echo 'The bear ate 3 snakes, then ate 50% of the fish from the river.' |
sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]/ /g'
The bear ate   snakes  then ate     of the fish from the river
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sed 's/[^A-Za-z]/ /g;' myfile.txt
```